# Verbal equivalent of "correspondent"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

one of the definitions of the word "correspondent" is a person with whom one converses through writing: is there a corresponding ;-) word for a person with whom one converses vocally (either in person or via telecommunications)?

Comment: *Correspondent*. A common usage of this term when referring to vocal communication is found on televised news broadcasts.

Comment: The _speaker_ of a sentence or utterance is to be distinguished from its intended _addressee(s)_. The first is the referent for _I_, and the second is the referent for _you_. Anybody else is third person.

Comment: *Interlocutor* is fun to say.

Comment: Uh, *talk-buddy*?

Comment: StoneyB can you make that an answer that I can accept? That's the kind of word I wanted

Answer (score 0):

**Correspondent**, cor·re·spon·dent \ˌkȯr-ə-ˈspän-dənt, ˌkär-\ noun -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/correspondent)

> a person whose job is to send news to a newspaper, radio station, or television program often from different places around the world;
>
> one who has regular commercial relations with another;
>
> one who contributes news or commentary to a publication (as a newspaper) or a radio or television network often from a distant place